# pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: offset overflow while concatenating arrays when do lora-finetuning

Tags: python, large-language-model

I'm a deep learning beginner and I'm trying to fine-tuning llama-13B with LORA by table understanding dataset about 40GB

```
def run_sft(
    model_args: "ModelArguments",
    data_args: "DataArguments",
    training_args: "Seq2SeqTrainingArguments",
    finetuning_args: "FinetuningArguments",
    generating_args: "GeneratingArguments",
    callbacks: Optional[List["TrainerCallback"]] = None
):
    dataset = get_dataset(model_args, data_args)
    model, tokenizer = load_model_and_tokenizer(model_args, finetuning_args, training_args.do_train)
    dataset = preprocess_dataset(dataset, tokenizer, data_args, training_args, stage="sft")

    if training_args.predict_with_generate:
        tokenizer.padding_side = "left" # use left-padding in generation

    if getattr(model, "is_quantized", False) and not training_args.do_train:
        setattr(model, "_hf_peft_config_loaded", True) # hack here: make model compatible with prediction

    data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        pad_to_multiple_of=8 if tokenizer.padding_side == "right" else None, # for shift short attention
        label_pad_token_id=IGNORE_INDEX if data_args.ignore_pad_token_for_loss else tokenizer.pad_token_id
    )

    # Override the decoding parameters of Seq2SeqTrainer
    training_args_dict = training_args.to_dict()
    training_args_dict.update(dict(
        generation_max_length=training_args.generation_max_length or data_args.cutoff_len,
        generation_num_beams=data_args.eval_num_beams or training_args.generation_num_beams
    ))
    training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(**training_args_dict)

    # Initialize our Trainer
    trainer = CustomSeq2SeqTrainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        data_collator=data_collator,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        compute_metrics=ComputeMetrics(tokenizer) if training_args.predict_with_generate else None,
        **split_dataset(dataset, data_args, training_args)
    )

    # Keyword arguments for `model.generate`
    gen_kwargs = generating_args.to_dict()
    gen_kwargs["eos_token_id"] = [tokenizer.eos_token_id] + tokenizer.additional_special_tokens_ids
    gen_kwargs["pad_token_id"] = tokenizer.pad_token_id
    gen_kwargs["logits_processor"] = get_logits_processor()

    # Training
    if training_args.do_train:
        train_result = trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint=training_args.resume_from_checkpoint)
        trainer.save_model()
        trainer.log_metrics("train", train_result.metrics)
        trainer.save_metrics("train", train_result.metrics)
        trainer.save_state()
        if trainer.is_world_process_zero() and finetuning_args.plot_loss:
            plot_loss(training_args.output_dir, keys=["loss", "eval_loss"])
    create_modelcard_and_push(trainer, model_args, data_args, training_args, finetuning_args)
```

when training,this err occurs and I don't understand.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "/fs/fast/u2019000171/envs/llama_factory/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/builder.py",
> line 1989, in _prepare_split_single
> writer.write_table(table)   File "/fs/fast/u2019000171/envs/llama_factory/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_writer.py",
> line 583, in write_table
> pa_table = pa_table.combine_chunks()   File "pyarrow/table.pxi", line 3638, in pyarrow.lib.Table.combine_chunks   File
> "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 154, in
> pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status   File "pyarrow/error.pxi",
> line 91, in pyarrow.lib.check_status pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: offset
> overflow while concatenating arrays.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/u2019000171/BOWEN/code/llama_factory/src/train_bash.py", line
> 14, in 
> main()   File "/home/u2019000171/BOWEN/code/llama_factory/src/train_bash.py", line
> 5, in main
> run_exp()   File "/home/u2019000171/BOWEN/code/llama_factory/src/llmtuner/train/tuner.py",
> line 26, in run_exp
> run_sft(model_args, data_args, training_args, finetuning_args, generating_args, callbacks)   File
> "/home/u2019000171/BOWEN/code/llama_factory/src/llmtuner/train/sft/workflow.py",
> line 28, in run_sft
> dataset = get_dataset(model_args, data_args)   File "/home/u2019000171/BOWEN/code/llama_factory/src/llmtuner/data/loader.py",
> line 83, in get_dataset
> dataset = load_dataset(   File "/fs/fast/u2019000171/envs/llama_factory/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/load.py",
> line 2582, in load_dataset
> builder_instance.download_and_prepare(   File "/fs/fast/u2019000171/envs/llama_factory/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/builder.py",
> line 1005, in download_and_prepare
> self._download_and_prepare(   File "/fs/fast/u2019000171/envs/llama_factory/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/builder.py",
> line 1100, in _download_and_prepare
> self._prepare_split(split_generator, **prepare_split_kwargs)   File
> "/fs/fast/u2019000171/envs/llama_factory/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/builder.py",
> line 1860, in _prepare_split
> for job_id, done, content in self._prepare_split_single(   File "/fs/fast/u2019000171/envs/llama_factory/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/builder.py",
> line 2016, in _prepare_split_single
> raise DatasetGenerationError("An error occurred while generating the dataset") from e datasets.exceptions.DatasetGenerationError: An
> error occurred while generating the dataset

update datasets and pyarrow don't work for me...